# Azure Role Assignment to AAD group fails with Terraform

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, roles, azure-service-principal

I am trying to assign contributor rights on a resource group to an Azure Active Directory Group using Terraform. The Terraform script I use looks like this:

```
# Deploy Resource Groups
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "rg-companyname-syn-env-100"
  location = "westeurope"
}

# Retrieve data for AAD CloudAdmin groups
data "azuread_group" "cloud_admin" {
  display_name        = "AAD-GRP-companyname-CloudAdministrators-env"
  security_enabled    = true
}

# Add "Contributor" role to Cloudadmin AAD group
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "cloud_admin" {
  scope                = azurerm_resource_group.rg.id
  role_definition_name = "Contributor"
  principal_id         = data.azuread_group.cloud_admin.id
  depends_on           = [azurerm_resource_group.rg]
}
```

If I run this I receive the following error:

```
╷
│ Error: authorization.RoleAssignmentsClient#Create: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client '<application_object_id>' with object id '<application_object_id>' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over scope '/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/rg-companyname-syn-env-100/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/<role_assignment_id>' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
│ 
│   with azurerm_role_assignment.cloud_admin["syn"],
│   on rg.tf line 15, in resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "cloud_admin":
│   15: resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "cloud_admin" {
│ 
╵
```

**Note** the AAD Group (AAD-GRP-companyname-CloudAdministrators-env) already has the **Owner** role on the subscription used.
Is there somebody that knows a fix for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue occur today after someone else in the team had changed the service principal my deployment ran under to a contributor rather than owner of the subscription. Assign the role the role "owner" of the subscription to the service account your deployments run under

Comment: I strongly advise against giving a service principal the owner role. There is a reason why DevOps is a primary attack vector, and why [Broken Access Control](https://owasp.org/Top10/A01_2021-Broken_Access_Control/) was moved to the #1 spot on OWASP Top 10

Answer (score 2):

Whichever principal (either you, a service principal or managed identity assigned to a build agent) likely has the built in Azure role `Contributor` which can manage resources, but not Role Based Access Control (RBAC). So that is the reason you are getting a 403 Unauthorized response.

`Contributor` role is allowed to read, but not write role assignments. Since you are using Terraform, I would suggest creating a custom role definition which will allow `write` as well as `delete` so you can use `terraform destroy`

You can create a custom role definition by clicky-clicking in the portal, [azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/definition?view=azure-cli-latest#az-role-definition-create) or Terraform (snippet below); executed by someone with the Owner role.

Once you have a custom role assignment with the appropriate permissions then assign the principal that is executing the `terraform apply` with that custom role.

```
 data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {
 }

 resource "azurerm_role_definition" "role_assignment_write_delete" {
     name  = "RBAC Owner"
     scope = data.azurerm_client_config.current.subscription_id
     description = "Management of role assignments"
    
     permissions {
         actions = [
             "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write",
             "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/delete",
         ]
         not_actions = []
     }
    
     assignable_scopes = [
         data.azurerm_client_config.current.subscription_id //or management group
     ]
 }
```